# Manually rendering Zend_View with layout enabled

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I'm creating a mail service within my application that has the body of the email stored in the database prior to sending it out to recipients.

Each mail body is a partial view script that has the necessary parameters injected into it via Zend_View.

What I want to do is create a 'mail' layout that can wrap around each of these partials,
but I can only seem to get either the layout content or the view content; not both at once.

**What I've got**

```
$scriptPath = 'test_mail';

$view = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('view');
$view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/mail/views/scripts/partials/');
$view->layout()->setLayout('mail');

var_dump($view->layout()->render($scriptPath));
```

However, all I receive is the view script content.

My layout is looking something like this:

```
<table class="mail">
    <!-- Snip -->
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
    <!-- Snip -->
</table>
```

I know this is possible. I don't want to do:

```
$layout->content = $view->render($scriptPath);
```

I assume I'm going the wrong way about this. Is it that I need/ don't have the layout controller plugin registered and somehow need to trigger this to get the output?

I suppose I could just create a custom layout class and take care of the rendering myself but wanted to see what others said first.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using email layout, multiple view templates for different kinds of emails and extended Zend_Mail class for setting desirable body:

```
class MyMail extends Zend_Mail
{    
    public function setBodyView($script, $params = array())
    {
        $layout = new Zend_Layout(array('layoutPath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts'));
        $layout->setLayout('email'); // Your email layout
        $view = new Zend_View();
        $view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . PATH_TO_MAIL_TEMPLATES);
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {    
           $view->assign($key, $value);
        }

        $layout->content = $view->render($script . '.phtml');
        $html = $layout->render();
        $this->setBodyHtml($html);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I was trying to see if I could make use of the layout controller plugin somehow so it could set $layout->content for me instead (like in the postDispatch). This is probably the best workaround otherwise I guess. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I using %mail_body% pattern in my mail template.

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$view = $layout->getView();
$mail_template = $view->render('template.phtml');
$returnYourReadyTemplate = str_replace('%mail_body%', $mail_body, $mail_template);
```

in template.phtml :

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body >
<div style="margin:30px 20px 10px 20px">
%mail_body%
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I think you could just get by with $view = new Zend_View(); here? Based on the context you've given I mean (so I might be missing something). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Why not? :) `$mail_template` contains all html from template, so you can manipulate with it. I'm not sure, but you can try `$view->partial('template.phtml', $your_data_array);` to add some arguments in a loop.